# How to determine current branch in post-rewrite hook

Tags: git, git-branch, githooks

Background: I want to have `post-rewrite` hook that will push changes automatically to the upstream repo (I'm the only user of it, and I use it to share my own work between different machines). The post-rewrite is the only time when I have to use force push, so I'd like it to be something like:

```
currentBranch=...
git push [origin] $currentBranch -f
```

In other questions it's been suggested to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` or `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`. These both correctly determine current branch when used outside of `post-rewrite` script, but not inside of it. If I set my `post-rewrite` script to be:

```
#!/bin/bash
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

Console output will be:

```
$ git rebase [...]
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: [...]
HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
myBranch
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
myBranch
```

#### EDIT:

Short script to replicate my issue:

```
# setup the repo
git init test
cd test
echo "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" >> .git/hooks/post-rewrite
echo "git symbolic-ref --short HEAD" >> .git/hooks/post-rewrite
chmod a+x .git/hooks/post-rewrite

# create the root branch
git checkout -b root
touch test
git add test
git commit -m "test commit for root" test

# branch out
git checkout -b test1
touch test1
git add test1
git commit -m "test commit 1" test1

# branch out again
git checkout -b test2 root
touch test2
git add test2
git commit -m "test commit 2" test2

# rebase
git rebase test1
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

Expected output would be (after cutting out previous messages):

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: test commit 2
test2
test2
test2
test2
```

Instead, I get

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: test commit 2
HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
test2
test2
```

Comment: Curious; looking at the interactive rebase script (`vim $(git --exec-path)/git-rebase--interactive`) I see it running the post-rewrite hook after restoring HEAD as a symbolic reference, if it was one at the start.  The same goes for `git-rebase--merge`.  Oddly, `git-rebase--am` doesn't call the post-rewrite hook at all (bug?).  Perhaps this is git-version-dependent; what version of git are you using?

Comment: @torek: it's 1.9.5 from XCode command line tools

Comment: I've just switched to 2.6.1 and the same problem persists. I just tested and `git rebase --interactive` works (i.e. it correctly resolves HEAD in post-rewrite script), just the standard `git rebase [otherBranch]` fails. Now that you pointed out where these scripts live, I played with them a little bit and in a default `git rebase [currentBranch]` case it's `git-rebase--am` that's being called, which calls `git am --rebasing [...]` command - and that's where the post-rewrite is being called from.

Comment: Aha, that explains the problem.  It's `git-am` (in the same directory) that calls the post-rewrite hook, and it calls it *before* the rebase code has moved back to the branch.  This seems like a bug.  If the goal is to have both `git am` and `git rebase` call the post-rewrite hook, the `am` script needs to call it only when *not* rebasing, and leave the rebase case to the rebase code so that it can switch the branch back first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between Filip Wolski's additional information (edit and comments) and manual investigation, I now believe this is a bug in git.

When you invoke a non-interactive rebase, git runs its `git-rebase--am` script (out of the `git --exec-path` directory), which detaches from the current branch and uses `git am ... --rebasing ...` to apply patches (as produced by `git format-patch` with various flags).

There is an exception here: if you use the keep-empty-commits flag, the script uses `git cherry-pick` to copy commits, including empty commits.

In any case, at the end of `git-rebase--am`, the script gets back on the branch and adjusts the branch label.  However, this is after the `git am` script has finished and returned.  It's the `git am` script that invokes the post-rewrite hook, and that happens too soon, before the "current branch" notion has been restored.

This seems to make for *two* bugs:

- If you use the `-k` or `--keep-empty` flag, the post-rewrite script won't run at all.
- Otherwise you hit this case, where the post-rewrite hook runs, but while in detached-HEAD state.

It seems to me that `$(git --exec-path)/git-am` needs to leave the notes adjusting and post-rewrite hook to the `git-rebase--am` script.

Until the bug is fixed, one workaround is to use interactive rebase (you can set the environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to `:` or `true` to make it run without an edit session).

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what can I do in terms of reporting that. I've noticed that 2.6.2 release notes mention a rewrite of git-am. I can't easily test it on my current setup but will get to it eventually.